# Where I have error when convert vue js code to one html file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I found sample vue js project from [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-conversational-form-example?file=myForm.js) And now I want run this code in one html file using vue js.

I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/space10-community/conversational-form@1.0.1/dist/conversational-form.min.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <MyForm></MyForm>
  </div>
  <script>
    Vue.component('MyForm', {
      template: '<div class="myForm"></div>',
      styles: [`
        .myForm {
          position: relative;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
        }
      `],
      methods: {
        setupForm: function () {
          const formFields = [
            {
              'tag': 'input',
              'type': 'text',
              'name': 'firstname',
              'cf-questions': 'What is your firstname?'
            },
            {
              'tag': 'input',
              'type': 'text',
              'name': 'lastname',
              'cf-questions': 'What is your lastname?'
            }
          ];

          this.cf = ConversationalForm.startTheConversation({
            options: {
              submitCallback: this.submitCallback,
              preventAutoFocus: true,
            },
            tags: formFields
          });
          this.$el.appendChild(this.cf.el);
        },
        submitCallback: function () {
          var formDataSerialized = this.cf.getFormData(true);
          console.log("Formdata, obj:", formDataSerialized);
          this.cf.addRobotChatResponse("You are done. Check the dev console for form data output.")
        }
      },
      mounted: function () {
        this.setupForm()
      },
    });
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it's not work. Where I have any errors? Thanks!

Project documentation website: https://space10-community.github.io/conversational-form/docs/1.0.0/getting-started/

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a technical description. What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use PascalCase for components in an HTML file. You need to change:

```html
<MyForm></MyForm>
```

to:

```html
<my-form></my-form>
```

The problem is that when the browser parses the HTML it converts all the tag names to upper-case, so the word boundaries are lost.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Component-name-casing-in-templates-strongly-recommended

I'm not familiar with the `ConversationalForm` library but I also had to change:

```js
this.cf = ConversationalForm.startTheConversation({
```

to:

```js
this.cf = conversationalform.ConversationalForm.startTheConversation({
```

After that it all seemed to run successfully, though the DOM nodes are hidden by default.